# Login page insted of login prompt in Sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, security, modal-dialog, login

I have been create a Team Suite site in Sharepoint 2013.When any body try to start seeing site pages a logon window like below image display :

[image]

How I can show custom login page instead of this window?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should configure Forms Based Authentication to have this behavior. There are many FBA tutorials online.

Comment: Please provide more details.